# Disable elements of the firefox 57 UI for TreeStyleTab

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, tree-view, firefox-57

I recently upgraded from firefox 55 to firefox 58 nightly and many extensions have to be updated. Treestyletabs is the only extension that I really use and it has been reimplemented as a sidebar panel. The difference is that it now has a giant bar at the top like this:

[image]
saying in really big letters Tree Style Tab. I was able to eliminate the tabs at the top of the screen by adding

```
#tabbrowser-tabs { visibility: collapse !important; }
```

to my `.mozilla/firefox/???/chrome/userChrome.css` file. I want to know if there is something similiar I can do to hide the sidebar panel header while still keeping the sidebar panel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> mannigfaltig said:
>
> I've added a modification that removes any margin at the top:
>
> ```
> #TabsToolbar, #sidebar-header {
>   visibility: collapse !important;
> }
>
> #TabsToolbar {
>   margin-bottom: -21px !important;
> }
> ```
>
> Then go to the hamburger menu > Customization and check "Title Bar" at
>   the bottom left. Then it pretty much looks like FF 56.
>
> I've also changed the style of TSTs in the add-on settings (all the
>   way at the bottom; not in userChrome.css) such that the tabs don't
>   take up as much vertical space and to hide the close box button (and
>   only show it on the mouse-over event):
>
> ```
> .closebox {
>   display: none
> }
>
> .tab:hover .closebox {
>   display: block;
> }
>
> .tab {
>   padding-top: 0px;
>   padding-bottom: 0px;
> }
> ```
>
> You can make `.tab` even tighter:
>
> ```
> .tab .icon {
>   padding-top: 2px; /* reducing it by 2px */
>   padding-bottom: 2px;
> }
>
> :root {
>   --tab-height: 22px; /* reducing it by 4px */
> }
> ```
>
> https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15342379

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly https://i.imgur.com/aWTw67f.png

Comment: Reducing the vertical space settings shown here resulted in tabs overlapping each other when collapsed. The settings that work can be found on [treestyletab wiki](https://github.com/piroor/treestyletab/wiki/Code-snippets-for-custom-style-rules).

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the direct answer but a suggestion. You don't have to fully disable this section while not all of the sub-sections have shortcuts to bring them to the foreground. Instead you can use this css in `~/.mozilla/firefox/???/chrome/userChrome.css` to shrink it.

```
.sidebar-header,
#sidebar-header {
  font-size: 1em !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Give a chance to [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/) it is a plugin (FF, Chrome) that enables you to modify the appearance of any website.

Comment: I don't believe the currently available version works with Firefox V57+.

Comment: There's a WebExtension version of Stylish now, but it doesn't really help with this; it's geared towards restyling *page content*, but the question at hand is about altering the Firefox *browser chrome*.

Comment: I have it running now with v58.0.2 (64-bit)